# Bing search API not available in your market place

Tags: api, azure, bing-api

I wanted to use [Bing search API](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) for my website but the page says "Not available in your market".

What does this note mean? How can I use this API?

I am currently in India, is there any way I could access this API as this is the last and only option I have. Google image search api has limit of 100 queries per day and Yahoo search api is not free any more.

Limit of 5000 queries/month on bing is what I need. Please let me know if there is any way to access this.

Comment: Got the same for me.

Comment: if you found some solution to that . please share that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Was fixed when I went to:

1) Logged in to Microsoft Azure Marketplace

2) My Account

3) Selected "United Kingdom" as my country

4) Save

5) Application ==> searched for: Search API

6) Selected the product I need ==> it was available

The unavailability was derived from my account country.